# How do you listen for an event on a context menu item?

Tags: javascript, onclick, contextmenu, addeventlistener

I am trying to listen for a click on the "open link in new tab" contextmenu item on the browsers default contextmenu (NOT a custom contextmenu). I want to do some javascript right before the page opens in a new tab. Or even stop the default behavior, do my javascript and then window.open() the link myself.

I've seen how I can listen for the contextmenu like this...

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {});
```

But that won't allow me to figure out if a specific item is clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You can't listen to every user interaction, but you can guess some. If you have to do actions before you open a new window, use a custom contextmenu.

You can do some kind of workaround, like listening for `window.onblur` and/or `window.mousemove` after the contextmenu was opened. I had several situations where i had to handle similar challenges to yours, but not everything can be captured.

For example the mousemove doesn't trigger, while the contextmenu is open but `document.hasFocus()` is true. As soon as the user clicks inside the contextmenu and if the mouse is still above the current document, mousemove is triggered twice at the exact same spot. If combined with a click event, the user closed the contextmenu with a left-click into the DOM. If the user closed the contextmenu with ESC, keyup is triggered, but not if the user selects something with keyboard.

```
/*
 auxclick can be any mouse key except primary
 contextmenu may also trigger, if you use the contextmenu key on the keyboard
 but it fires a MouseEvent with values from a KeyboardEvent
 */
["contextmenu", /*"mousemove", */ "click", "auxclick", "keydown", "keyup"].forEach(name => {
  document.addEventListener(name, function(e) {
    if (document.visibilityState != "hidden") {
      console.log(name, document.hasFocus(), document.activeElement, e.key || e.screenX, e.key || e.screenY);
    }
  });
});

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(e) {
  console.log("visibilitychange", document.hasFocus(), document.visibilityState, window.screenX, window.screenY);
  if (window.screenX == window.screenY && window.screenX == -32000 && document.visibilityState == 'visible') {
    console.log("restored");
  }
});

/*
  this won't trigger if the user switches from outside 
  the window directly into an iframe or between multiple
  iframes see https://crbug.com/967430
  monitor document.hasFocus() changes and fire a custom focus/blur event on change.
 */
window.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
  console.log("focus", document.hasFocus());
});

window.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
  console.log("blur", document.hasFocus(), document.visibilityState, window.screenX, window.screenY);
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (document.visibilityState == "hidden") {
      if (window.screenX == window.screenY && window.screenX == -32000) {
        console.log("minimized");
      } else {
        console.log("maybe new or other tab with focus or view source?");
      }

    } else if (!document.hasFocus()) {
      if (window == window.top) {
        console.log("maybe new window or dev tools");
      } else {
        console.log("maybe new window, dev tools or I'm an iframe and my parent got selected");
      }
    } else if (document.hasFocus()) {
      console.log("Maybe entered an iframe or canvas?", document.activeElement);
    }
  }, 1);
});

setInterval(() => console.log("interval", document.hasFocus(), document.activeElement), 2000);
```